# How to get a list of sub tuple if given some indexes of tuple in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

There is a list of tuple like

```
l = [(1, 2, 'a', 'b'), (3, 4, 'c', 'd'), (5, 6, 'e', 'f')]
```

I can use

```
[(i[0], i[2], i[3]) for i in l]
```

to get the result

```
[(1, 'a', 'b'), (3, 'c', 'd'), (5, 'e', 'f')]
```

But if given a variable list such as `[0, 2, 3]`,  how to get the similar result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), like this

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> getter = itemgetter(0, 2, 3)
>>> [getter(item) for item in l]
[(1, 'a', 'b'), (3, 'c', 'd'), (5, 'e', 'f')]
```

If you have a list of indices, then you can [unpack them](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) to the `itemgetter`, like this

```
>>> getter = itemgetter(*[0, 2, 3])
>>> [getter(item) for item in l]
[(1, 'a', 'b'), (3, 'c', 'd'), (5, 'e', 'f')]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a generator expression and `tuple()` to pull out specific indices:

```
[tuple(t[i] for i in indices) for t in l]
```

or you can use a [`operator.itemgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a callable that does the same:

```
from operator import itemgetter

getindices = itemgetter(*indices)
[getindices(t) for t in l]
```

where `indices` is your list of indexes. This works because `operator.itemgetter()` just happens to return a `tuple` object when retrieving multiple indexes.

Demo:

```
>>> l = [(1, 2, 'a', 'b'), (3, 4, 'c','d'), (5, 6, 'e','f')]
>>> indices = [0, 1, 2]
>>> [tuple(t[i] for i in indices) for t in l]
[(1, 2, 'a'), (3, 4, 'c'), (5, 6, 'e')]
>>> getindices = itemgetter(*indices)
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [getindices(t) for t in l]
[(1, 2, 'a'), (3, 4, 'c'), (5, 6, 'e')]
```